# HTML Table - multiple rowspans

Tags: html, html-table, tablerow

I want to create a table which looks like below :

```
______________________________________________________________
|              |                |      Category1             |
|              |   Platform1    |____________________________|
|              |                |      Category2             |
|              |________________|____________________________|
|   Build      |                |      Category1             |
|              |                |____________________________|
|              |                |      Category2             |
|              |   Platform2    |____________________________|
|              |                |      Category3             |
|______________|________________|____________________________|
```

I wrote some code, but I don't think it is correct. As I am quite new to HTML, can someone please give me some suggestions:

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that:

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">Build</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Platform1</td>
    <td>Category1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Platform2</td>
    <td>Category1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6nqNn/)